# How to make sure that, the http request from javascript use http/2 protocol?

Tags: javascript, http

when ever we do HTTP request, we create XMLHttpRequest object in java script or

```
$.ajax({ url:"...", type: "GET", success:function(){}, error : function{} });
```

in jQuery.

All these use HTTP 1. If we want to use HTTP/2 protocol, how we can achieve it.

Comment: You should check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921726/use-http-2-to-make-api-calls-from-javascript). I think it is releated